# How to use args to prevent multiple calls of a function in this case?

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing, args

I have a multiline plotter which takes in the parameter of lists of n lists [u, u1...], essentially plotting n lines on a single graph. However, in order to plot them I have to call them from my other function which returns the individual list for different T = 50, 150,...

```
x, u = heat_eq(50, both_ice, 0, 0)   # here im calling 8 lists to plot them
x, u2 = heat_eq(150, both_ice, 0, 0)
x, u3 = heat_eq(250, both_ice, 0, 0)
x, u4 = heat_eq(350, both_ice, 0, 0)
x, u5 = heat_eq(450, both_ice, 0, 0)
x, u6 = heat_eq(550, both_ice, 0, 0)
x, u7 = heat_eq(650, both_ice, 0, 0)
multiline(x, [u, u2, u3, u4, u5, u6], "length(m)", "Temperature(Degree Celsius)", [25, 50, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650], "time(s)", 21)
```

In this case my heat_eq() would have to be called many times if i was to plot more lines. Is there a way of combining for loops with *args such that it allows me to

```
for i in range(*args):
      x, [u, u2, u3, u4, ...] = heat_eq("different T(s) here", both_ice, 0, 0)
return x, [u, u2, u3, ...]
```

so that I could

```
multiline(x, [u, u2, u3, u4, ...], "length(m)", "Temperature(Degree Celsius)", [25, 50, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650], "time(s)", 21)
```

? the manipulation of args is actually very confusing.

Edit: Thought I'd put more info about my functions to help you with better understanding the question.
So my `heat_eq` goes like this:

```
def heat_eq(T, bc, ti, tf):
"""
T is a number here
bc is the boundary condition function
ti and tf are both constants
"""
t = np.linspace(0, T, Nx + 1)
x = np.linspace(0, T, Nx + 1)
# define other stuff here


# initiate a matrix here
A = some matrix
A = bc(A, some other constants)  # A gets put into BC spits out A with boundary condition values included.
for n in range(something):
    Here A does something to produce data points into a list u

return x, u
```

So when I call it with say a boundary condition `both_ice(A, constant)` I would do

```
x, u = heat_eq(50, both_ice, 0, 0)
```

Hope this is enough info for you to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you that `heat_eq` receives a list as input parameter

```
def heat_eq(my_list):
    # Do whatever
    return x, another_list
```

If you prefer to unpack arguments as `*args` you should pass whatever `both_ice, 0, 0` is to named parameters and then you'll be able to unpack each unnamed argument as a list:

```
def both_ice():
   pass

def heat_eq(*args, func=both_ice, num_1=0, num_2=0):
    # Now you have a list of arguments
    for elem in args:
        do_whatever(elem)
    return x, list_of_elems
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that my `both_ice` here is a function for a boundary condition, which takes in other parameters `both_ice(list_a, list_b, list_c, constant)` which is called into `heat_eq` to be used inside. Not sure how that changes your answer?

Comment: That's not a problem though, I edit the answer to fit your problem

Comment: Hiya I've put in more info about my question, pls have a look :)